# Add icon class to HTML5 button from code behind

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html

I have a HTML5 button that I'm using as a SAVE/CREATE button and the text is changed from code behind depending on the condition. No issues here, but I need to add an icon style element to my button from code behind and this isn't working:

```
<button typeof="button" id="btnSaveCreate" class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" onserverclick="btnSaveCreate_ServerClick"><i class="fas fa-road"></i></button>
```

I'm trying to alter the text and add a font awesome icon from code behind like this:

```
btnSaveCreate.InnerText = "Save <i class=\"fas fa-road\"></i>";
```

That doesn't work and neither does this:

```
btnSaveCreate.InnerText = "Save";
btnSaveCreate.Attributes.Add("class", "fas fa-road");
```

Comment: are you using MVC views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `<asp:Button>` (Tested and working)

```
<asp:Button typeof="button" id="btnSaveCreate" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

and use the character code to set the icon in the code behind

```
btnSaveCreate.CssClass = "fas";
btnSaveCreate.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("Save &#xf018;");
```

---

Alternatively, as you said (also tested and working):

```
<button typeof="button" id="btnSaveCreate" class="btn btn-danger" runat="server"></button>
```

and the code behind:

```
btnSaveCreate.Attributes.Add("class", "fas");
btnSaveCreate.InnerText = Server.HtmlDecode("Save &#xf018;");
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. CssClass and .Text doesn't exist so I must use: `btnSaveCreate.InnerText = Server.HtmlDecode("Create New Project &#xf018;");
                btnSaveCreate.Attributes.Add("class", "fas");`

Comment: Ah yes, you might need to be using an `<asp:Button>`. Did the code you tried work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.InnerText`, use `.InnerHtml`